# Best way to create routes in apache Camel

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, esb, enterprise-integration

I'm new to camel and we're developing a service to expose a SOAP interface and consume a REST api.

My question is about the design of the solution. Our service exposes 10 methods, so i have to create 1 route for each and also set headers of the request to the restapi. I'm trying to think about a way to create routes with a configure method cleaner. I googled some patterns, but i didn't find any that suits with camel. I think that something like a factory could be useful.

Is there any standard and optimized way to create routes with cleaner code?
I don't know if i'm being clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look to WSDL 2 REST project https://github.com/jboss-fuse/wsdl2rest

it will generate the routes automatically. I tis covering a subset of wsdl, you can report an issue on the project if your case is not covered.

Please note that it is available through UI in [Eclipse](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-migrate-your-soap-web-service-to-rest-with) and [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-wsdl2rest).

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful but it's not what i'm needing right now. Maybe i didn't explain myself. I was looking for some kind of pattern which helps me to organize better route creation